# How to make a SVG fully responsive.

Tags: html, css, svg

Been playing around with SVGS today and I'm wondering how I would make what I've done fully responsive. I've made this JS fiddle below to show everyone.

```
            <div id="cont" data-pct="25">
                <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <defs>
                        <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="80%" cy="60%" r="70%" fx="60%" fy="40%">
                            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(33,204,185);" />
                            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(31,98,205);stop-opacity:1" />
                        </radialGradient>
                    </defs>                    
                    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
                    <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x152qo95/1/

At the moment it has fixed widths and heights.

I can make it work without the width being 100% but can't get it aligned properly with the height.

Looking forward to learning solutions to this.

Comment: There's no such attribute as viewPort, you presumably meant viewBox

Comment: Nice one Rob. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Does that fix things for you?

Comment: It has certainly changed things.. I'm not sure if it has fixed it yet though

Comment: shouldn't it be `viewBox="0 0 200 200"`?

Comment: Actually mate that does work.. thanks

Comment: ccprog. Could you put your fix into a answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewBox was too small. This should work:

```
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Comment: I had to make a few other changes but this lead me to my solution